# Which migration class should I extend to migrate user accounts?

Tags: 7, migrations

I want to migrate users from a Drupal 5 site to a Drupal 7 site.

I installed the [Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) and [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) modules. I know I have to make a custom module extending the built in classes of migrate_d2d module to migrate users.

Which migration class should I extend while making the custom class?
Is it correct that the custom class should be placed in the *user.inc* file?

Comment: Are you migrating users from a Drupal site and content from a non Drupal site?

Comment: no. I am migrating both from drupal5 site

Answer (score 2):

Upgrade from Drupal 5 to 6, then from 6 to 7. That's it. No further modules or writing your own code is needed, users and content will migrate just fine. You only need Migrate and other modules if you have some special stuff on your site, like Organic groups. CCK version 7 will be needed in most cases, but that's all in the documentation.

Here's the documentation, follow carefully:

From 5 to 6: https://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade/5/6

From 6 to 7: https://drupal.org/documentation/upgrade